# create pool for MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, connection-pooling

hello I want to create a pool for MySQL but I got an error

> Cannot read property 'createPool' of undefined
> notice,

I installed MySQL for my project

```
require("dotenv").config();

const { mysql } = require("mysql");

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";

const connectionString = `mysql://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@${process.env.DB_HOST}:${process.env.DB_PORT}/${process.env.DB_DATABASE}`;

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionString: isProduction ? 
  process.env.DATABASE_URL : connectionString,
  ssl: isProduction
});

module.exports = { pool };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The npm package `mysql` doesn't export an object containing a property `mysql`. You either have to import the whole object

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
```

or only the function

```
const { createPool } = require("mysql");
```

and use it like

```
const pool = createPool({
  connectionString: isProduction ? 
  process.env.DATABASE_URL : connectionString,
  ssl: isProduction
});
```